# hide farbtastic color code

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a great http://acko.net/blog/farbtastic-jquery-color-picker-plug-in/

I need to do 2 things:

a. Hide color code that we can see under

```
<input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="color"  name="color" value="#123456" />
```

b. Keep this code to some other hidden field.

How it can be done?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to remove the color code from the readonly input and keep it in another input ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera. Correct. But another input should be hidden. I just don't want to give user too many code. Just an option to see the selected  color only and not the color code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="color" name="color" />
    <input type="hidden" id="colorValue" name="colorValue" />
</form>
<div id="colorpicker"></div>​
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var picker = $.farbtastic('#colorpicker');
    picker.setColor("#fff");
    picker.linkTo(function onColorChange(color) {
        $('#color').css({'background-color':color});
        $('#colorValue').val(color);
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FMpxd/2/).

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see the script you're referring, page won't load, but I'm pretty sure you just need to change the type into `hidden`, when it's hidden you can also remove the `readonly` attribute:

```
<input type="hidden" id="color" name="color" value="#123456" / >
```

I assume that script automatically updated the field you mentioned, if it's hidden it will still update it.